# Double foreach for createFormBuilder Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I ask you to help me with the double foreach in this code, I need that, where the comment is, there should be a listing of the stage steps, and I do not know how to do this in this code, thank you in advance

```
 $formStage = $this->createFormBuilder($projectStages);
    foreach ($projectStages as $projectStage) {
        $formStage = $formStage
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    $projectStage->getTitle() => [
                        $projectStage->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[0]->getTitle() => 'v1',
                        //enumeration of stage steps
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
    }

    $formStage->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Update Project Stages'));
```

Comment: I hope you are aware, that you do *not* have to do everything between array braces, right? you can just create an extra `$choices` helper var and write to it and later use it.

Comment: @Jakumi , yes, this is just an example of what i need

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is CollectionType. Or I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you just want to merge arrays with php where the comment is? Like [$projectStage->getTitle() =>array_merge($arrayA, $arrayEnumSteps)] ?